# How to implement recursion when searching for an unique sudoku (python)?

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a function with recursion, but the return I get is empty each time... The code is as follows: first a random grid is generated (`random_puzzle()`). This is transformed from a string to an array, after which it is solved and checked if the created sudoku is unique (`solve(grid)`). What I want the code to do is keep making a new sudoku until it has found a puzzle that is unique. Why does my recursion not work?
Thanks in advance!

```
grids={}
Grids={}
final_grid = []

def solve(grid):
    global uniq, count, proc_time
    tic = time.perf_counter()
    if uniq < 2:
        for y in range(9):
            for x in range(9):
                if grid[y][x] == 0: 
                    for n in range(1,10):
                        if possible(y,x,n):
                            grid[y][x] = n 
                            solve(grid)
                            count += 1
                            grid[y][x] = 0
                    return grid
                
    uniq += 1
    toc = time.perf_counter()
    proc_time = toc - tic
#     print('Time needed to solve Sudoku: '+str(toc - tic)+' seconds')
#     print('Steps needed:'+str(count))
    return grid

def random_puzzle(N=25):
    values = dict((s, digits) for s in squares)
    for s in shuffled(squares):
        if not assign(values, s, random.choice(values[s])):
            break
        ds = [values[s] for s in squares if len(values[s]) == 1]
        if len(ds) >= N and len(set(ds)) >= 8:
            return ''.join(values[s] if len(values[s])==1 else '.' for s in squares)
    return random_puzzle(N) 


def make_grid():
    uniq=0
    count=0
    Grids=random_puzzle(N=25)
    mat = Grids.replace('.','0')
    grid = np.zeros([9,9])
    countx = 0 
    county = 0
    for j in mat:
        if countx >= 8:
            grid[county,countx] = j 
            countx = 0
            county += 1
        else:
            grid[county,countx] = j
            countx += 1   
    final_grid = solve(grid)
    if  uniq > 1:
        make_grid()          
    elif uniq == 1: 
        return final_grid

test = make_grid()
print(test)
```

Comment: you use ```return```   you should return something..   like ```return grids``` if that's the thing you want to return.  and also,  I noticed you have ```test = make_grid()``` and then ```print(grids)```.   shouldn't that be ```grids = make_grid()```?

Comment: Thank you Ewong! I changed it, but it still does not work....

Comment: it'll only return the result if ```uniq == 1```.

Comment: Yes, true, however I want the function to keep looking until it has found an unique solution, but it is not doing that right now....

Comment: I'm not seeing where you change the value for ```uniq```.   it seems to be 0 all the time.

Comment: Aah sorry, yes, it is a global variable that is updated in the solver function. I will post it.

Comment: I noticed that in ```solve()``` you have another ```return grid```  could that be returning too early and thus not letting ```uniq``` be incremented?  btw, what's ```random_puzzle```?

Comment: Hmmm it works fine when I define some grids of which I know they are unique or non-unique, so without the random_puzzle() function. So I am not sure if that is where the problem will be, but I can try it!